# topological space $T_B$

Tags: general-topology

a  topological   space $X$ is called $T_B$ if  every compact subset is closed.

Is $X \times X$,  $T_B$ when $X$ is  $T_B$ ?

If it is not true, which conditions do need to $X \times X$ be $T_B$?

Comment: A counterexample is any compact non-Hausdorff KC-space, i.e. a space where the compact sets and the closed sets coincide. Then the diagonal $\triangle$ is not closed in $X\times X$ as that would imply Hausdorffness of $X$, but $\triangle\approx X$ is compact. Hence $X\times X$ is not KC.

Comment: Do you mean if X is Hausdorff and KC  ,$X \times X$ will be KC ($T_B)$?

Comment: @Alireza: Of course: every Hausdorff space is automatically $KC$ (or $T_B$, if you prefer), and the product of two Hausdorff spaces in Hausdorff. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/466564/12042) I gave a the specific example of the one-point compactification of $\Bbb Q$ as a compact $KC$ space whose square is not $KC$; of course $\Bbb Q^*$ is not Hausdorff.