# Does path-connected imply simple path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space, i.e., for any two points $a,b\in X$ there is a continuous map $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$. Note that beyond continuity little is required about $\gamma$.

> Is it always possible to make $\gamma$ a *simple* (=injective) curve? (Of course we consider only the case $a\ne b$). 
>   If the answer depends on $X$, what are some mild sufficient conditions on $X$?

If $X$ is sufficiently nice, e.g., an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, the answer is "yes";  more generally, what one would call "locally simplepath-connected" suffices (the set of points reachable from $a\in X$ by a simple curve is both open and closed).
Also, for arbitrary $X$ it is clear that a single instance of self-crossing can be short-cut. But for infinitely many possible short-cuts the situation *may* become somewhat hairy, I'm afraid.

**EDIT:** To avoid *Mike Miller*'s counterexample (indiscrete topology on $X$ with $|X|<|\Bbb R|$), let's at least assume that $X$ is Hausdorff. At any rate, $|X|\ge|\Bbb R|$ is a *necessary* condition - I am still looking for "as mild as possible"  *sufficient* conditions ...

Comment: Annular region can be done by simple paths.

Comment: You at least want some simple assumption like "Hausdorff". The indiscrete topology on any set of cardinality less than $\Bbb R$ provides a counterexample otherwise for point-set reasons.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't know if you read French, but there are elements of answer here: http://allken-bernard.org/pierre/weblog/?p=1180. In particular in the message of JLT.

Comment: The usual term for "simplepath-connected" is "arc-connected", which may make it easier to search for results on this.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555101/equivalence-of-path-connectedness-and-arc-connectedness-for-hausdorff-spaces).

Comment: @EricWofsey - Is a simple path really always an arc? The inverse of a continuous function may not be continuous.

Comment: @mr_e_man: It's equivalent for Hausdorff spaces, since any continuous injection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is an embedding.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Following the [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522642/does-path-connected-imply-simple-path-connected#comment3111364_1522642) given by* [mathcounterexamples.net](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187663/mathcounterexamples-net), *let me post a community-wiki translation (and rewording and elaboration) of a [comment by JLT on a weblog by Pierre Bernard](https://web.archive.org/web/20130729030221/http://allken-bernard.org/pierre/weblog/?p=1180):*

**Theorem.** Every path-connected Hausdorff space is simplepath-connected.

Before proving this theorem, we need some lemmas.

**Lemma 1.** Let $Y$ be a perfect (=no isolated points) compact metric space. Then there exists a diffuse probability measure on $Y$.

*Proof.*
It is known that such $Y$ contains a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set $C$. Moreover, the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, transported to $C$ via the map $\sum a_k2^{-k}\mapsto \sum a_k3^{-k}$ (where $0.a_1a_2\ldots$ is the binary representation of $x\in[0,1)$) is a diffuse probability measure on $C$ and thus provides us with a diffuse probability measure on $Y$. $_\square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $Y$ be a perfect compact subset of a  metric space.
Then there exists a diffuse probability measure on $Y$ with support $Y$.

*Proof.*
For each $n$, $Y$ can be covered by a finite number $N(n)$ of open balls $B(x_{n,i},\frac1n)$, $1\le i\le N(n)$, of radius $\frac1n$. Let $Y_{n,i}=Y\cap\overline{B(x_{n,i},\frac1n)}$. The $Y_{n,i}$ are perfect compact metric spaces, hence by lemma 1 there exists a diffuse probability measure $\mu_{n,i}$ on $Y_{n,i}$. Then
$$\mu(A):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{N(n)}\frac1{2^nN(n)}\mu_{n,i}(A\cap Y_{n,i}) $$
is a diffuse probability measure on $Y$. Its support intersects each $Y_{n,i}$ hence contains all of $Y$. On the other hand, the support is contained in the union of all $Y_{n,i}$, which is contained in $Y$. $_\square$

Recall that any open set $U\subseteq(0,1)$ can be written as disjoint union of countably many open intervals, $U=\bigsqcup_{i\in N}(a_i,b_i)$ with $N\subseteq\Bbb N$.

**Definition.** Let $f\colon [0,1]\to X$ be a curve. Let $U=\bigsqcup_{i\in N}(a_i,b_i)\subset [0,1]$ an open set. We say that $U$ is *$f$-shortcutable* if $f(a_i)=f(b_i)$ for all $i\in N$.

**Lemma 3.** Let $f\colon [0,1]\to X$ be a curve with $X$ Hausdorff. Let ${(a_i,b_i)}_{i\in I}$ be a chain (with respect to $\subseteq$) of $f$-shortcutable intervals. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ is $f$-shortcutable.

*Proof.*
We have $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=(a,b)$ with $a=\inf a_i$, $b=\sup b_i$.
Assume $f(a)\ne f(b)$ and let $V_a, V_b\subset X$ be open neighbourhoods separating $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then for some $\let\epsilon\varepsilon\epsilon>0$, $[a,a+\epsilon)\subseteq f^{-1}(V_a)$ and $(b-\epsilon,b]\subseteq f^{-1}(V_b)$.
Find $i,j\in I$ with $a_i\in [a,a+\epsilon)$, $b_j\in(b-\epsilon,b]$. Per chain property, $a_j\le a_i$ or $b_i\ge b_j$. In the first case $f(a_j)=f(b_j)\in V_a\cap V_b$, in the second case $f(b_i)=f(a_i)\in V_a\cap V_b$, contradiction. Hence $f(a)=f(b)$ and $(a,b)$ is $f$-shortcutable. $_\square$

**Lemma 4.**
Let $f\colon [0,1]\to X$ be a curve with $X$ Hausdorff.
Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a chain (with respect to $\subseteq$) of $f$-shortcutable open subsets of $(0,1)$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ is $f$-shortcutable.

*Proof.* The connected components of the union are open intervals.
Consider one such component $(a,b)$ and a point $c\in(a,b)$. For $i\in I$ let $V_i$ be the component of $U_i$ containing $c$, or $V_i=\emptyset$ if $c\notin U_i$. Then the $V_i$ are a chain of $f$-shortcutable intervals.
By lemma 3, their union is an $f$-shortcutable interval $(a',b')\subseteq (a,b)$. If $a'> a$, then $a_i\in U_i$ for some $i$ and by openness  $[a',a'+\epsilon)\subseteq U_i$ for this $i$. As $a'+\frac\epsilon2\in V_j$ for some $j$, we conclude that $[a',a'+\epsilon)\cup V_j\subseteq U_k$ for some $k\in\{i,j\}$, which implies $a'\in(a',b')$, contradiction. We conclude $a'=a$. Similarly, $b'=b$. $_\square$

We are now finally ready to prove the theorem.

*Proof of Theorem.* Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $f\colon [0,1]\to X$ a path with $f(0)\ne f(1)$.
The set of $f$-shortcutable open subsets of $(0,1)$ is non-empty (contains $\emptyset$) and is inductively ordered according to lemma 4. By Zorn's lemma, there exists a maximal $f$-shortcutable $U_M$. As above write it as disjoint union of open intervals $$U_M=\bigsqcup_{i\in N}(a_i,b_i)$$ and then define
$$ x\sim y\iff x=y\lor\exists i\in N\colon \{x,y\}\subset [a_i,b_i].$$
This is an equivalence relation, where transitivity follows from maximality of $U_M$: Assume $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$, say $\{x,y\}\in[a_i,b_i]$ and $\{y,z\}\in[a_j,b_j]$. If $i\ne j$ then from $(a_i,b_i)\cap (a_j,b_j)=\emptyset$ we conclude $y\in\{a_i,b_i\}\cap\{a_j,b_j\}$ (and specifically $y\notin U_M$); but then $f(a_i)=f(b_i)=f(a_j)=f(b_j)$ so that $U_M\cup\{y\}=U_M\cup(\min\{a_i,a_j\},\max\{b_i,b_j\})$ is $f$-shortcutable, contradicting maximality. Hence $i=j$ and clearly $x\sim z$.

The equivalence classes of $\sim$ are closed: In fact the class of $x$ is either $\{x\}$ alone, or a single interval $[a_i,b_i]$ or possibly the union of two adjacent closed intervals $[a_i,x]\cup [x,b_j]$ (though this possibility actually does not occur per maximality of $U_M$).
Let $J=[0,1]/{\sim}$. Being a quotient of the  compact Hausdorff space $[0,1]$ by an equivalence with closed equivalence classes, the space $J$ is also compact Hausdorff.
We can define a map $g\colon J\to X$  by letting $g([t]):=f(\inf [t])=f(\sup[t])$. This $g$  is injective and continuous. The theorem follows if we can show that $J\approx [0,1]$.
Let $Y_0=[0,1]\setminus U_M$. Then $Y_0$ is compact and has no isolated points except possibly $0$ and/or $1$. Let $Y$ be $Y_0$ minus its (at most two) isolated points (in other words, $Y=\overline{(0,1)\setminus U_M}$).
By lemma 2 there exists a diffuse probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ with support $Y$.
Consider $h\colon[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $x\mapsto \mu([0,x])$. This is a map  with $h(0)=0$ and $h(1)=1$; it is continuous because $\mu$ is diffuse. Moreover, for $x<y$
$$\begin{align}h(x)=h(y)&\iff \mu(\left]x,y\right[)=0 \\
&\iff\left]x,y\right[\cap\operatorname{supp}(\mu)=\emptyset\\
&\iff \left]x,y\right[\cap Y=\emptyset\\
&\iff \left]x,y\right[\cap Y_0=\emptyset\\
&\iff \left]x,y\right[\subseteq U_M\\
&\iff x\sim y \end{align}$$
Consequently, $h$ factors over $J$, thus showing $J\approx [0,1]$. $_\square$

---

*Remark:* The part where the homeomorphism $J\approx [0,1]$ is shown allows an alternative proof not involving the measure-theoretic lemmas 1 and 2 (which are not required for the proof of the theorem anywhere else):
We can define an order on $J$ by letting $[x]<[y]\iff x<y$, which is well-defined because the equivalence classes are in fact non-overlapping closed intervals. The topology of the quotient space $J$ is the order topology induced by this order because that is the case for $[0,1]$.
Also, $J$ is separable because $[0,1]$ is.
$J$ is complete: If $A\subset J$ is non-empty and bounded from above by $[x]\in J$, then it has a least upper bound; indeed, the preimage of $A$ in $[0,1]$ has a least upper bound $y\le x$ and then $[y]$ is a least upper bound for $A$. The same goes for lower bounds. The order is also dense as for $[x]<[y]$ we find $[x]<[z]<[y]$ with $z=\frac{\sup [x]+\inf[y]}2$, again because the equivalence classes are closed intervals.
In particular, $J$ does not consist only of the endpoints $[0]$ and $[1]$ so that $J\setminus\{[0],[1]\}$ is a [nonempty, separable, complete, dense, endless total order and hence isomorphic to $\Bbb R$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43148/basic-results-with-three-or-more-hypotheses/43165#43165). Add back the two endpoints and we arrive at $[0,1]$ as desired.

---

*Remark:*
Invoking Zorn's lemma means invoking the Axiom of Choice.
As many prefer to avoid that axiom (if they have the choice), we can try to find a maximal shortcutable set more constructively:

We still assume $X$ Hausdorff.
Let $U$ be $f$-shortcutable and assume $U$ is not maximal.
Each $f$-shortcutable proper superset of $U$ has a component $(a,b)$ that is not a component of $U$. In other words,
the set
$$ A=\{\,(a,b):0\le a<b\le 1, f(a)=f(b), \{a,b\}\subsetneq [0,1]\setminus U\,\}$$
is non-empty. Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be minimal with
$$ A_n=\{\,(a,b)\in A:b-a\ge\tfrac 1n\,\}\ne\emptyset$$
and then let $\alpha =\inf\{\,a:(a,b)\in A_n\,\}$.

**Claim.** There exists $b$ with $(\alpha,b)\in A_n$.

*Proof.* Otherwise we find a strictly decreasing sequence $(a_k)$ with $a_k\to a$ together with a sequence $(b_k)$ such that $(a_k,b_k)\in A_n$. Then $(b_k)$ has an accumulation point $b\in [a+\frac1n,1]$.
Assume $f(a)\ne f(b)$ and as $X$ is Hausdorff let $V_a,V_b\subset X$ be open neighbourhoods separating $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then $f^{-1}(V_b)$ contains infinitely many $b_k$ and $f^{-1}(V_a)$ contains almost all $a_k$, hence for some $k$ we have $a_k\in f^{-1}(V_a)$, $b_k\in f^{-1}(V_b)$ and so $f(a_k)=f(b_k)\in V_a\cap V_b$, contradiction.
We conclude that
$f(b)=f(a)$. Clearly, $b-a\ge\frac 1n$. We have $a\notin U$, $b\notin U$ because all $a_k,b_k$ are $\notin U$. Finally, there are infinitely many $a_k\notin U$ between $a$ and $b$, and the claim follows. $_\square$

So we let $\beta=\sup\{\,b:(\alpha,b)\in A_n\,\}$. By continuity, $f(\beta)=f(\alpha)$ and ultimately we define $S(U)=U\cup (\alpha,\beta)\supsetneq U$. (For the sake of completeness, define $S(U)=U$ if $U$ is maximal).
For each ordinal $\nu$, we define an $f$-shortcutable set $U_\nu$ such that $\nu'<\nu$ implies $U_{\nu'}\subseteq U_\nu$. We do this  by the recursion $U_\nu=S(\bigcup_{\nu'<\nu}U_{\nu'})$. (Regarding the union, see lemma 4).
There must exist an ordinal $\nu$ with $U_\nu=U_{\nu+1}$, and this is a maximal $f$-shortcutable set as desired.

Comment: Also, an alternate way to prove that $J\cong [0,1]$ is to show that its topology is induced by the canonical ordering on $J$ and note that $J$ is a bounded complete separable dense linear order, so by a standard back-and-forth argument it is order-isomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Regarding the proof that $J\cong [0,1]$ I wanted to explicitly follow the referenced argument by JLT (though I modifed much of the rest to a large extent until *I* could wrap my head around it). One reason for this was that I got confused by the French *séparé* apparently meaning *Hausdorff* and not *separable*. :) -- Also I noticed that O forgot to make this community wiki as promised ...

Comment: @EricWofsey On further thougt about your comment, I suppose that such an order-topology argument is much better - especially as it is probably better known than the claim about Cantor sets (which I admittedly only *translated* as "it is known that")

Comment: Well, the order topology argument is probably more elementary, but the measure argument is still quite elegant and is probably a useful technique to be aware of in more general situations (where there isn't an ordering).  In any case, thank you for translating and sharing this beautiful argument!

Comment: Can one do this without appealing to the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: @Neal: I believe the use of Choice in the Zorn's lemma argument is avoidable, since whenever you have a non-maximal shortcutable open set, you can canonically choose a larger one (essentially, take the least $n$ such that there is a new shortcut $(a,b)$ such that the distance between $b$ and $a$ when you identify the $J$ obtained by the shortcuts you already have with $[0,1]$ is $\geq1/n$, and then among such shortcuts choose the one with $a$ minimal and $b$ minimal for the given $a$).  The use of choice in showing $J\cong [0,1]$ can also be avoided easily in my version of the argument.

Comment: (Note that in general, defining "the $J$ obtained by the shorcuts you already have" is a bit tricky because the relation $\sim$ described in the answer might not be an equivalence relation; you have to take the closed equivalence relation it generates, and use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff to be sure that $g$ is well-defined on the $J$ this gives you.)

Comment: Inspired by Mike Miller's comment to the question. This theorem implies that no countable path-connected Hausdorff space can exist. [Countable _connected_ Hausdorff spaces do exist](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46986/). On Math Overflow there is [a thread about this observation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214526/).

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP asks for conditions, which are "mild as possible," I'll point out that the Hausdorff condition can actually be weakened slightly.

**Definition:** A space $X$ is *$\Delta$-Hausdorff* if the image of every path $\alpha:[0,1]\to X$ is closed in $X$.

We have the following.

**Theorem:** Every path-connected, $\Delta$-Hausdorff space is arcwise connected.

*Proof.* [You can find the proof in this expository note.](https://www.wcupa.edu/sciences-mathematics/mathematics/jBrazas/documents/Constructing_arcs_from_paths_9-9-21.pdf)

At its heart, this proof is basically the one given in the accepted answer, where the idea is to make choices of loops to delete. Although the converse of the theorem is certainly false, I find it interesting that the following biconditional holds: a space $X$ is $\Delta$-Hausdorff if and only if the loop-deletion procedure can be applied to every non-loop path to produce an injective path.

It's also worth pointing out that it *is* possible to prove the theorem directly without using the axiom of choice. Such [a proof is due to R. Borger](https://www.worldcat.org/title/recent-developments-of-general-topology-and-its-applications-international-conference-in-memory-of-felix-hausdorff-1868-1942-berlin-march-22-28-1992/oclc/29847631), but this paper is probably difficult to come by if you don't have access to a University library.

The improvement is modest but properties like the $\Delta$-Hausdorff (or [weakly Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_Hausdorff_space)) property are often used in algebraic topology and are strictly weaker than the Hausdorff property. For instance, the weakly Hausdorff property is a convenient separation axiom in the category $CG$ of [compactly generated spaces](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf). The $\Delta$-Hausdorff property is to the category of [$\Delta$-generated spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Delta-generated+topological+space) as the weakly Hausdorff property is to compactly generated spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are looking for conditions as mild as possible, it's worth noting that as long as one is only asking for an injective path joining two points (rather than a homeomorphic image of an interval), one can relax the Hausdorff condition to [$US$](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000099), or unique sequential limits.

While it is likely possible to wade through various proofs and show that Hausdorff can be replaced by $US$ in each individual step (with or without modifications), we alternatively can make a quick argument to extend the result from the Hausdorff case to the $US$ case as follows:

If $(X,\tau)$ is $US$, then $(X, \tau_s)$ is $US$ and [sequential](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000079) (sequentially closed subsets are closed), where $\tau_s$ is the family of sequentially open sets in $\tau$.  Note that since $[0,1]$ is sequential, $f\colon [0,1]\to X$ is continuous with respect to $\tau$ if and only if it is continuous with respect to $\tau_s$ (in both cases, the continuous maps are precisely the sequentially continuous maps).  Hence $(X,\tau)$ is injectively path connected if and only if $(X,\tau_s)$ is injectively path connected.

Therefore, it suffices to show that when $X$ is $US$, sequential, and path connected, $X$ is injectively path connected.  But since $X$ is $US$ and sequential, [it is "strongly $KC$"](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000235) (countably compact subsets are closed), and a fortiori must be [weak Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000143).  Since the image of a map from a compact Hausdorff space into a weak Hausdorff space is again Hausdorff per [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/964546/1210477), it follows from the $T_2$ case of the theorem that every pair of points in $X$ is joined by an injective path.

##### Remark

Somehow this slipped by me on an initial reading:

> more generally, what one would call "locally simplepath-connected" suffices (the set of points reachable from $a\in X$ by a simple curve is both open and closed).

This need not be the case for a general path-connected, locally simply path connected space.  The line with a doubled origin is a counterexample.