# Is there a difference between arc-wise connectivity or path-wise connectivity?

Tags: general-topology, definition, plane-curves

When authors refer to arc-wise connectivity, do they mean path-wise connectivity?

I am studying space filling curves and when reading books, I either come across the concept of arc-wise connectivity or path-wise connectivity.

Can arc-wise connectivity and path-wise connectivity be taken to mean the same thing?

Comment: They can,but some authors requires the path to be one-to-one in order to be called arc

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien So because I am looking at it in the context of space filling curves and it is not possible for a space filling curve to be injective, can I assume they mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes,i think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first review what I would consider to be the standard definitions of these terms.  A space $X$ is path-connected if for any $x,y\in X$ there is a continuous map $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.  A space $X$ is arc-connected if for any $x,y\in X$ there is an *injective* continuous map $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.

That said, I have also occasionally seen people that treat them as synonymous, with the definition I gave for "path-connected" applying to both.  Note that for reasonably nice spaces, the two notions are equivalent.  In particular, any Hausdorff path-connected space is automatically arc-connected (this is fairly complicated to prove; see [Does path-connected imply simple path-connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522642/does-path-connected-imply-simple-path-connected), for instance).  So if you are only thinking about Hausdorff spaces, there is no need to distinguish them.