# Is a path-connected set always Jordan-path connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, path-connected

A path in set $E$ is a continuous function
$$\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow E, $$
with $A:=\gamma(a)$ its starting point and $B:=\gamma(b)$ its ending point. 
Any two points $A, B$ in a **path-connected set** can be connected by a path, with $A, B$ as its starting and ending points.  
A **Jordan path** $\gamma$ is an injective path. 
Any two points $P, Q$ in a  **Jordan-path connected set** can be connected by a Jordan path.

---

**Question:** For any **path-connected** set $E$, is $E$ always **Jordan-path connected**?

---

When there are at most countably many self-intersecting points, it's possible to 'cut' the loop and make the path a Jordan one. But I got problems when there are uncountably many self-intersecting points on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S$ the Sierpiński space. It has two points $x$ and $y$, where $y$ is open (formally, the open sets are $\varnothing, \{y\}$ and $\{x,y\}$).

The map $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to S$ given by $\gamma(0) = y$ and $\gamma(1) = x$ is continuous: the preimage of the only non-trivial open set $y$ is $[0,1)$, which is open.

This shows that $S$ is path-connected, but it can't be Jordan path connected by cardinality considerations.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522642/does-path-connected-imply-simple-path-connected?rq=1) answer by Hagen von Eitzen shows that if $E$ is geometric enough (and by that I mean Hausdorff) then the answer is yes.