# Does every nonconstant curve admit a nonconstant simple subcurve?

Tags: general-topology, curves, plane-curves

The Wikipedia page on the [inscribed square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem) mentions that an analog of the problem involving triangles instead of squares does hold. However, it doesn't mention anything about triangles inscribed in arbitrary, possibly non-simple, closed plane curves, and I couldn't find any results online for arbitrary closed plane curves either. Naturally, the result is trivial for all closed plane curves that admit some Jordan subcurve, so I started wondering whether all closed plane curves admit Jordan subcurves, but I had no luck finding a proof or a counterexample.

So, I originally posed five questions. The first question was whether nonconstant closed plane curves always admit nonconstant Jordan subcurves, and the second was an analog of the question for general $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. MoisheKohan pointed out in the comments that a closed plane curve whose image is an interval is a counterexample to both. As such, I am now posing a separate but related question in addition to the three other unresolved questions below (still ordered in ascending generality.)

**Modified question on closed Euclidean curves**: what are some nontrivial necessary or sufficient conditions on nonconstant closed Euclidean curves $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$ to guarantee the existence of a nonconstant *simple* closed subcurve $\gamma_{s} : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $Im(\gamma_{s}) \subseteq Im(\gamma)$ and $\gamma_{s}(0) = \gamma_{s}(1)$? (e.g. if the set of points where $\gamma$ is injective has a subset of points that is dense-in-itself, then is that sufficient?)

For **open Euclidean curves on closed intervals**: let $\gamma : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an arbitrary Euclidean path satisfying $\gamma(0) \neq \gamma(1)$. Does there exist a nonconstant simple subcurve $\gamma_{s} : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Im(\gamma_{s}) \subseteq Im(\gamma)$ and $\gamma_{s}(0) = \gamma(0), \gamma_{s}(1) = \gamma(1)$?

For **general Euclidean curves**: let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary interval, and $\gamma : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an arbitrary Euclidean curve. If $\gamma$ is nonconstant, then does there exist an interval $I_{s} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a nonconstant simple subcurve $\gamma_{s} : I_{s} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Im(\gamma_{s}) \subseteq Im(\gamma)$?

For **general curves**: same statement as the general Euclidean curve question, just with an arbitrary topological space $X$ replacing $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Of course not, just take any curve whose image is an interval.

Comment: @MoisheKohan In this case, a closed curve refers to a curve C on a closed interval [a, b] where C(a) = C(b), not to a curve where Im(C) is a closed set.

Comment: I know. Now construct a closed curve whose image is an interval.

Comment: Ah, of course. I will include a note in the problem body that the closed Euclidean case is resolved.

Comment: Actually, in light of the fact that the only "open" cases are the other questions, I will change the titling and rework the body to keep the question relevant.

Comment: Examples where both the injectivity set and it's complement are dense in the interval but the image is a dendroid, are well known in hyperbolic geometry as limit sets of **totally degenerate Kleinian groups.** And the map to the dendroid from the circle is called a **Cannon-Thurston** map.

Comment: Fascinating, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple closed curves question, let $A\subseteq [0,1]$ denote the points $t\in [0,1]$ on which $\gamma$ is injective, i.e., $f^{-1}(\{f(t)\})=\{t\}$.

One sufficient condition is that if $A$ has any interior points, then certainly we can construct a simple closed curve in $\text{Im}(\gamma)$, since after reparametrizing so that $(0,\frac{1}{2}]\subseteq A$, we can apply the path-connectedness, hence arc-connectedness, of $\text{Im}(\gamma|_{[\frac{1}{2},1]})$ to obtain an arc $\gamma'$ joining $\gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ and $\gamma(1)$ whose image lies inside of  $\text{Im}(\gamma|_{[\frac{1}{2},1]})$, and concatenating $\gamma'$ with  $\gamma|_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ then gives a simple closed curve inside of $\text{Im}(\gamma)$.

On the question of whether it's enough for $A$ to merely be dense in itself, I strongly believe the answer is no (nor is it even enough to be dense, period), though I haven't written up a counterexample carefully (see the remark for a rough sketch).

The answer for open and general curves in Euclidean spaces, as well as Hausdorff spaces in general, is yes, since [path connectedness implies arc connectedness for Hausdorff spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1528947/1210477). If you drop Hausdorff then for a counterexample (even to a relaxed definition of "simple" that simply requires a curve to not be self-intersecting), let $X$ be any set with cardinality less than the reals, equipped with the trivial topology, then there are many nonconstant paths into $X$, but all are self-intersecting.

##### Remark

In general, to get a counterexample of a closed curve, injective on a dense set, for which the image contains no simple closed curve, it is easy to see we need an image that is uniquely arcwise connected.  A likely counter-example would be a fractal tree-like set, given in the plane for example by starting at stage $0$ with $S_0:=[-1,1]\times \{0\}\cup \{0\}\times [-1,1]$, and then at each stage $n$, constructing $S_n$ by adding a scaled copy of $S_0$ by a factor of $\frac{1}{4^n}$ centered at the midpoint of each segment in $S_{n-1}$. The closure of $\bigcup_n S_n$ is then the image of our curve.

I *think* the parametrization of this set by a closed curve should result in a dense set of points for which $\gamma$ is injective (including, certainly, the pre-images of the extreme points at each stage of the construction). Moreover, I believe if the parametrization is done in a fairly straightforward way, the curve will actually be injective on a set of full measure even.

The parametrization isn't especially complicated (just traverse each self-similar portion of the tree with equal time spent in each branch), but is somewhat cumbersome to write down.  The full-measure argument comes from showing the preimage of each finite stage $S_n$ under $\gamma$ has measure $0$, and arguing that only these points can be non-injective.

However, I have not carefully written the details of this (especially the full measure part), and don't know of a reference where this is done, so take it with something of a grain of salt for the time being.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! This answer, combined with Moishe Kohan's comment, should settle all of the non-open-ended questions I had. Of course, I'm still open to hearing about any other interesting necessary/sufficient conditions that people come up with.