# Is every compact space compactly generated?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I am using the definition of compactly generated space from [The Category of CGWH Spaces](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf), which is

> In $\mathbf{Top}$, a $k$-*closed* subset $Y\subset X$ is a set such that $u^{-1}(Y)$ is closed in $C$ for any $u: C\to X$ where $C$ is compact Hausdorff.
>
> A space is *compactly generated* if all $k$-closed subsets are closed.
>
> *locally compact* means every point has a local base of compact sets.

This is different from the definition from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space)

So, is any compact space compactly generated?

And, is any locally compact space compactly generated?

Comment: For your first question, if $X$ is compact Hausdorff, consider taking $C=X$ and $u$ the identity.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I want to know what about non-Hausdorff space

Comment: The term *compactly generated* is used differently by different authors. Sometimes is denotes a space where a subset is closed if it intersects each compact subset in a closed set, let's call these *c-spaces*. Other times it denotes a space as you describe it, but these are also called *k-spaces*. Both compact and locally compact spaces are c-spaces. So you are actually searching for a space that is a c-space but not a k-space.

Comment: It seems that both your question and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632320/weak-hausdorff-space-not-kc) require a space with *many* compact subsets which are not images of compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: By the way, is there any explicit example of a compact space, even non-T₀ one, to where a Hausdorff compact can’t be surjectively mapped?

Answer (score 10):

It seems the following.

We shall use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632320/71850) by Amathstudent and [its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/964546/71850) by Brian M. Scott.

We prove that each weak Hausdorff compactly generated $T_1$ space is $KC$.  Since there is a weak Hausdorff compact $T_1$ space, which is not $KC$ (see the space $\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*$ in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/964546/71850) by Brian M. Scott), this space is not compactly generated.

So, let $X$ be a weak Hausdorff compactly generated $T_1$ space and $Y$ be a compact subset of $X$. We claim that $Y$ is $k$-closed subset of $X$. Indeed, let $C$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $u: C\to X$ be a continuous map. Since the space $X$ is weak Hausdorff, the set $u(C)$ is closed in $X$. A set $u(C)\cap Y$ is compact as a closed subspace of a compact space $Y$. By Lemma 1, the space $u(C)$ is Hausdorff. So the set $u(C)\cap Y$ is closed in the space $u(C)$. Since the set $u(C)$ is closed in $X$, the set $u(C)\cap Y$ is closed in the space  $X$ too. Since the map $u$ is continuous, the set $u^{-1}(Y)= u^{-1}(Y\cap u(C))$ is closed in $C$. 
Since the space $X$ is compactly generated, the set $Y$ is closed in $X$. Hence $X$ is a $KC$-space.

Comment: Can you show a *k*-closed subset in your example that isn’t closed? Is it the diagonal?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi The diagonal is not closed as remarked Brian M. Scott, but it should be $k$-closed as I claimed in the old version of my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me with Brian’s answer? [I can’t understand anything there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465521/if-a-is-compact-and-b-is-lindel%c3%b6f-space-will-be-a-cup-b-lindel%c3%b6f/466564#comment2180494_466564).

Comment: @IncnisMrsi As for me, his arguments are too complicated. My intuition says the following. A space $Z$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal of the space $Z\times Z$ is its closed subset. And the space $\Bbb Q^*$ is not Hausdorff (in the opposite case it would be a countable compact Hausdorff space without isolated points, which contradicts Baire Theorem).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Brilliant. Just a minor note: weakly Hausdorff spaces are already $T_1$ (any point is closed being the image of some constant function $u\colon K\to X$). What about the second question about locally compact spaces? In $\mathbb{Q}^*\times\mathbb{Q}^*$ no point has a local base of compact sets so it does not disprove the conjecture "locally compact implies compactly generated".

Comment: Incidentally, your result shows that not every compact space is homeomorphic to a quotient of some locally compact Hausdorff space (compare this to the fact that every space is homeomorphic to a quotient of some Hausdorff space).

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: The diagonal in $\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*$ is indeed $k$-closed. This can also be deduced as follows: Since $\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*$ is weak Hausdorff, so is its $k$-ification $k(\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*)$ (this equippes the space with the final topology with respect to all maps from compact Hausdorff spaces). But a $k$-space is weak Hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed, see Neil Stickland's paper [CGWH](http://www.neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf‎). That means the diagonal is $k$-closed, but it's not closed as $\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Oh, and it's of course $k$-closed by Alex' lemma, as that shows that in a weak Hausdorff space every compact set is $k$-closed.

Comment: @johndoe I'll think about the second question about locally compact spaces.

Comment: The statements in the answer can be simplified slightly, since a weak Hausdorff space is always $T_1$.